What is the significance of bringing the door to Nippur in the Epic of Gilgamesh?
In Tablet V of the Epic of Gilgamesh, the main characters fell a giant cedar tree and turn it into a door. Enkidu then proposes bringing the door to Nippur.
In the translation by Sophus Helle, the relevant passage reads:

Enkidu worked his words, saying to Gilgamesh: "My friend, we have
felled a mighty cedar, whose topmost branches touched the skies.
Make a door of it: one hundred and twenty feet tall, forty feet wide,
and two feet thick.
It will all be one piece—pole, pivot, and swivel. Let the Euphrates
carry it to Enlil in Nippur, let it fill the temple of Nippur with
delight."
They gathered branches of cedar, cypress, and juniper, and made a
raft, loading it with ... Enkidu sailed on the raft ... and Gilgamesh
sailed on the head of Humbaba.

What is the significance of bringing the door to Nippur? Since Gilgamesh was the king of Uruk, i.e., another city, I would have expected them to rather bring it to their own city instead of Nippur.
From what I understand, Enlil is the god associated with Nippur, and Enlil also was the one who tasked Humbaba with guarding the Cedar Forest. Could it be that they first insult Enlil by killing Humbaba and then try to make up for it by sacrificing a fancy door for his temple?

Also later in Tablet VII, Enkidu curses the door and regrets not bringing it to Sippar (where there is the temple to Shamash):

"I would have grabbed my ax, I would have cut you down, and sailed on
you to Sippar, to the Shining Temple. I would have brought you to the
temple of Shamash and planted you i nthe gate of the Shining Temple."

But isn't he in Uruk in this scene?

Was there a temple in Nippur with a gigantic door? If there was, this would explain this episode.

"Enlil is the god associated with Nippur...". Enlil was also the most powerful of the gods, so its was not a good idea to upset him: your patron god might not be able to protect you.

Some translations provide some clarity on this matter, while others don't. For example, Andrew George's translation (Penguin, 1999, not to be confused with the translation included in the critical edition for Oxford University Press), which clearly identifies the tablets that were used for each part of the translation, says "Let the god Enlil delight in it!" (page 47). In order to understand why it would be important to please Enlil, we need to go back to the lines that precede Humbaba's death (page 44, square brackets by George):

The [great] gods will take against us in anger,
Enlil in Nippur, Shamas in [Larsa] ...

In his critical edition of the epic (The Babylonian Gilgamesh Epic: Introduction, Critical Edition and Cuneiform Texts · Volume 1, Oxford University Press, 2003, page 470), Andrew George makes the connection explicit:

From the tallest tree of all Enkidu then makes (or proposes to make) a great wooden door for the temple of Enlil in Nippur (292–8). The implication is that he hopes the gift will help to appease Enlil for the killing of the forest's guardian and the desecration of its sacred groves. (…) Humbaba's head plays no further role in the epic but in the Sumerian tale the heroic duo empty it out of their pack before Enlil in Nippur, who rebukes them for their sacrilege.

Benjamin R. Foster's translation (second edition, Norton, 2019) contains the following passage (page 47, square brackets by Foster):

[Enkidu] made ready to speak, saying to Gilgamesh:
[My friend,] we have made a wasteland of the forest,
[How] shall we answer for it to Enlil in Nippur (when he says):
"You slew the guardian as a deed of valor,
"But what was this, your fury, that you have decimated the forest?"

A few lines above this passage, Foster inserts an explanatory note or paraphrase saying that Enkidu and Gilgamesh (emphasis mine),

make a gigantic door that they float down the Euphrates as a gift to Enlil, to placate him for their killing the guardian of the forest.

Other scholars also assume that the door is intended to placate Enlil for the killing of Humbaba, the decimation of the forest or both. For example, Alan Lenzi writes in An Introduction to Akkadian Literature (Penn State University Press, 2019 , page 120),

(…) a repetitive exchange between [Gilgamesh and Enkidu] (…), in which Enkidu worries that killing Humbaba will anger Enlil, the high god of the pantheon. (…) The tablet concludes with the two heroes felling cedars in the forest and  sending them downstream. Enkidu also fashions a door to take back to Nippur as a votive offering to its resident deity, Enlil, perhaps to appease his anger for Humbaba's murder.

Dieter Bürgin writes in Psychoanalytic and Anthropological Considerations of Gilgamesh (Cambridge Scholars Publisher, 2021, page 25):

To appease Enlil and so to escape the atonement for the murder of Humbaba, [Enkidu] wants to build the door for the temple of the king of gods in Nippur.

The gift did not (sufficiently) appease the gods, which is one of the reasons why Enkidu had to die. (See also Why did the gods decide that Enkidu must die?)

I was too busy typing that up I didn't realize you beat me to it and had a few other quotes in store!

@cmw Yeah, I read five Gilgamesh translations and some related texts for the Gilgamesh reading challenge a few years ago and still keep an eye out for questions about the epic ;-)

Next stop is to learn Akkadian (or Sumerian, but you don't get the full epic that way). ;)

Thank you for this excellent and detailed answer!
